# Postgres Retrieve Values Conditionally?

Tags: postgresql

not sure if my title is exactly waht I want to accomplish but it was a guess. I'm trying to see if something like the following is possible in PGSQL.

Basically, I have a set of data that I want to pull no matter what. But, if certain columns of data *arent* null, then I want it to join another table and pull data referencing that data. So, for example, let's say I have data like:

User_Accounts:

| userid | companyname | first name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25df | Test Company 1 | Bob |
| 921f | Test Company 1 | Lawrence |
| 882s | Company test 2 | NULL |
| 8234 | Test Company 1 | Cleo |
| 8244s | Company test 2 | Paul |
| 825q | Test Company 1 | Bruce |
| 5552 | B Alpha Company | Lenny |

Baseball_Rosters:

| userid | baseball_team | company | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25df | Atlanta Aliens | Test Company 1 | P |
| 882s | Boston Bruisers | Company test 2 | DH |
| 8234 | California Craisins | Test Company 1 | 1B |
| 8244s | Tampa Titans | Company test 2 | P |
| null | Tampa Titans | Test Company 1 | P |
| 5552 | Tampa Titans | B Alpha Company | 2B |
| 5552 | Tampa Titans | B Alpha Company | SS |
| 921f | California Craisins | Test Company 1 | P |
| 825q | Boston Bruisers | Test Company 1 | P |

How would I perform a query to get a result like:

| userid | baseball_team | company | first name | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | Tampa Titans | Test Company 1 | null | P |
| 25df | Atlanta Aliens | Test Company 1 | Bob | P |
| 825q | Boston Bruisers | Test Company 1 | Bruce | P |
| 921f | California Craisins | Test Company 1 | Lawrence | P |

So essentially, inserting the firstname & lastname field if and only if userid is not null? And then to order by userid null first and then in order? Thanks for the help.

Comment: The question seems like a LEFT OUTER JOIN which is a SQL 101 topic. If you will be dealing with PostgreSQL regularly I'd suggest to use https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ as a reference to get familiar with the generic SQL syntax and commands. Or if you want a reference specific to PostgreSQL visit this site https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Like this:

```
SELECT baseball_rosters.user_id, baseball_team, comapny, first_name, position
FROM baseball_rosters
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_accounts ON user_accounts.user_id = baseball_rosters.user_id;
```